# is there a way to reduce this switch statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case

I was going to use an if statement but my assignment requires me to use a switch.

```
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5: return income = hours * 5;

case 6:
case 7: return income = hours * 6;

case 8:
case 9:
case 10: return income = hours * 7; ;

case 11:
case 12:
case 13:
case 14:
case 15: return income = hours * 7; ;

case 16:
case 17:
case 18:
case 19:
case 20:
case 21:
case 22:
case 23:
case 24: return income = hours * 10;

default: return 0;
```

Comment: You are also missing breaks

Comment: Is there a mathematical relationship between the case variable and the multiplier?  I can't discern one.

Comment: Why do you use the unnecessary cases? just leave them out

Comment: I would note that you could use the switch to return the rate and factor out the return:  `return income = hours * rate;`

Comment: @Thibaut they fall through to the next case, so cases 16-24 return the same thing.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I don't see any missing breaks.  The code doesn't need any breaks to do what it's trying to do.

Comment: @Thibaut There are no unnecessary cases that could be left out.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I don't need breaks since it's being used in a return type method.

Comment: @D Stanley the problem there is there's different rate for different hours so I found it easier to just multiply by a raw number.

Comment: @DStanley alright my bad

Comment: If your assignment requires a switch, then there is nothing you could do that's going to be meaningfully better.  There are of course lots of better things you could do that don't involve using a `switch`.

Comment: @HyperPXLZ I'm saying that all that changes between the cases is the constant - so use the switch to determine the constant and put the multiplication outside the switch.  It doesn't answer your question; just an observation.

Comment: return 7 is repeated

Comment: @Paparazzi thanks a lot. Didn't even notice that.

Comment: If you would provide more information about the context, perhaps there's a better place for the mandatory `switch`. Just guessing btw, if these 1-24 represent hours in a day, and the 5-10 is the hourly rate, what happens if someone starts at 8 and finishes at 12?

Comment: Does the assignment state that you use one statement only? Perhaps you could at some more information about the assignment in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is succinct as it can be. A `switch` statement at runtime is actually a jump-table so it is considerably faster than a series of `if()` statements, even if you coalesce the `if` statements into range expressions (e.g. `if( 1 <= x && x <= 5 )`). A `switch`'s set of `case` statements must be *complete* if you want to cover every case (which is why you can't use `switch` with non-integer values (note that `switch` with a `String` value is a special-case).

I cannot see an obvious mathematical relationship between the cases and the multiplicand it returns which could be used to greatly simplify it. However you can refactor the code to be conceptually easier to understand - I'd start by removing the `income = hours *` part and moving this to a standalone function that simply returns the hourly rate:

```
int GetHourlyRate(int hours) {
    switch( hours ) {
        case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5:
            return 5;
        case 6: case 7:
            return 6;
        case 8: case 9: case 10:
            return 7;
        case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15:
            return 8; // you put 7 in your original example, is that correct and not a typo?
        default:
            if( hours <= 24 ) return 10;
            return 0; // or throw an exception?
    }
}

int hourlyRate = GetHourlyRate( hours );
return income = hours * hourlyRate;
```

Still, a giant `switch`/`case` block is still not readable, even if you collapse it in the style I have done to save on vertical space (as C# is insensitive to whitespace).

One option to simplify it, at least visually, is to metaprogram using T4, which would make maintenance easier too:

```
<#
    using R = Tuple<Int32,Int32>;

    R[] hourlyRates = new R[] {
        new R( 5, 5 ),
        new R( 7, 6 ),
        new R( 10, 7 ),
        new R( 15, 8 ),
        new R( 24, 10 )
    };

    WriteLine("switch( hours ) {");

    for( Int32 r = 0, i = 1; r < hourlyRates.Length; i++ ) {

        WriteLine( "case {0}:", i );
        if( i == hourlyRates[r].Item1 ) {
            WriteLine( "return {0};", hourlyRates[r].Item2 );
            r++;
            if( r > )
        }
    }

    WriteLine("}");
#>
```

...which will generate your `switch` based on the `hourlyRates` list defined in the T4 file.